# Turn off volume button notification sound in Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications, audio, silent-mode

1) I get a beep sound every-time I increase the ringer volume using the side button in Samsung Galaxy S2. How can I turn of this sound. I have set the notifications sound to Silent. But still am getting this sound.

2) Also whenever I connect the charger, I am getting a notification sound. How can I make this to silent as well.?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any way to do this through the software. The only way I've found to disable the sounds is to go to `/system/media/audio/ui` on your phone and delete files `Volume-1.mp3` through `Volume-7.mp3` for the volume tones, and `Charger_Connection.ogg` for the connection tone. Just tested this on my phone and it does indeed work. You may want to back up the files first in case you want to restore them at some point. You may also have to be rooted to be able to remove the files.

Edit: Actually, I'm sure you'll need root, as I had to `su` in a terminal emulator to be able to do anything in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get rid of the beep on power connection by setting the notification sound to zero in `System > Sound > Volumes`.